# .htaccess rewrite rule won't unicode characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using the following ModRewrite to make my urls look cleaner:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1
```

It allows use of letters and numbers just fine, but it produces a 400 error when i try to use %, which I require to use unicode characters for # / ', etc.
Any reason behind this? Thanks.

Comment: What error messages do you see in your logs?

Comment: `[Sun Oct 30 16:17:15 2011] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/search/$3`

Comment: Hehe.. What input (url) did you offer, what result (url) did you get, and what's the relevant error message?

Comment: look at this , it's usefull :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `B` flag in your rewrite rule. take a look at [apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-#$%^&]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [B]
```

**Edit**:
mod_rewrite uses unescaped characters, so if you want to use unicode characters, use them in rewrite rule and  save `.htaccess` file in unicode!