# mod_rewrite: Check if query contains soft hyphen and remove it

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my http logs I see:
"GET /category/f%C2%ADile-to-download/ HTTP/1.1" 301
instead of "GET /category/file-to-download/ HTTP/1.1" 200
I discovered that %C2%AD is a soft hyphen (invisible symbol).

I need to check if a query to Apache contains a soft hypen and if it does to remove it. Any suggestions on the best method to locate soft hyphen and remove it?
I made some tests with RewriteRule, but got stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the referrer of the link? I would guess that the link is in a document (pdf or something?), and being split over two lines, which may result in the soft-hyphen.

Comment: For example comments in youtube are modified with soft hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @icabod

Currently I got this rule working in my case:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \xc2\xad [NC]
RewriteRule ([^\xc2\xad]*)[\xc2\xad]+([^\xc2\xad]*) /$1$2 [N,R=301,L,NC]
```

.htaccess should be in UTF-8 format as mentioned above.
`R=301` - redirect with HTTP code 301
`NC` - case insensitive
But it doesn't work with two soft hyphens in the different places of the URL like this:

> /category/f%C2%ADile-to-d%C2%ADownload/

Comment: The reason it probably doesn't work for multiple soft hyphens is that you have the `[L]` flag specified, which will stop any further rules from running. I guess this has precedence over `[N]`, which re-runs the rules. I would try removing the `[L]` flag.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, mod_rewrite uses [un-escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7949227/218597), so in order for you to correctly match the soft-hyphen and then remove it, you would need to edit and save your `.htaccess` file in [UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm) encoding (most modern editors will do this).

You will then need to enter a soft-hyphen into your rule.  The following will (*should!?*) remove a *single* soft-hyphen from your input, but as mentioned it relies on the file being in UTF-8 format:

```
RewriteRule ([^-]*)-([^-]*) $1$2
```

Note that you would need to replace the `-` with the actual UTF-8 dash.

Perhaps an easier option would be this:

```
RewriteRule ([^\xc2\xad]*)\xc2\xad([^\xc2\xad]*) $1$2 [N]
```

It uses the specific UTF-8 code you're seeing to remove it from the string.  The `[N]` should rerun *all* the rewrite rules, which will remove any remaining soft-hyphens.

Comment: Currently I got this working rule in my case `RewriteRule ([^\xc2\xad]*)[\xc2\xad]+([^\xc2\xad]*) /$1$2 [N,R=301,L]`