# htaccess RewriteRule, how do should it handle hex codes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following line of code in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/(.+)/$ mypage.php?a=$1
```

This rewriterule works most of the time. However, if I try passing a parameter like `C++`, which would be `mypage/C%2B%2B/` then it does not work properly.  It should go to `mypage.php?a=C%2B%2B`... but instead it seems to look like `mypage.php?a=c++` and so the the PHP code sees the value of `a=c<space><space>`

How can I update the RewriteRule to pass the hex coding to the rewritten url ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Trick is to use `B` flag**. As per the manual:

> The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric
>   characters before applying the transformation.

[**Read more about it here in doc**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b).

Your modified rule should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/(.+?)/?$ mypage.php?a=$1 [L,QSA,NC,B]
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I found the answer inside another StackOverflow post:  [How to encode special characters using mod_rewrite & Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache)

Thanks for the help.