# Apache proxy/redirect encoding ? and = in the query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, proxy, amazon-s3

I want to proxy from my Amazon S3 bucket like this:

This url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1
```

Proxy from this url:

```
http://mys3.bucket.com/www.mysite.com/page1
```

This is working with this rule

```
RewriteRule .* http://mys3.bucket.com/%{HTTP_HOST} [P]
```

However, the complication occurs when the url contains a query string.

This url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1?search=asdf
```

Should proxy this url:

```
http://mys3.bucket.com/www.mysite.com/page1?search=asdf
```

To work with S3, that needs to be encoded like this so that the query string is part of the key:

```
http://mys3.bucket.com/www.mysite.com/page1%3Fsearch%3Dasdf
```

Note that only the `?` and `=` should be encoded. `%` in the keys for values should be left alone.

How can you do this with Apache?

Answer (score 1):

This might work, and I belive you want the [B](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) flag to encode your query string:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://mys3.bucket.com/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,B,P]
```

I was not able to verify the `P` flag, but it works in my test with `L` instead of `P`.

Here is a bit more information about URL-encoding using `mod_rewrite`: 
[How to encode special characters using mod_rewrite & Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache)

If you encode the URL yourself you should look into the [NE](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) flag rather than `B` flag.

Hope it helps you forward.