# mod_rewrite not matching regexp

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a regexp that seems to work fine when tested [at regexp101.com](http://regex101.com/)
but that does not give me the same result within mod_rewrite.

So, the URL I am trying to rewrite is:

```
/modeles-voiture/Nissan/Qashqai+2
```

The expected result is:

```
/modeles.php?brand=Nissan&model=Qashqai+2
```

The rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?modeles-voiture [NC]

RewriteRule \/([A-Z][\-A-Za-z]+)\/([\+\-A-Za-z0-9]+$) /modeles.php?brand=$1&model=$2 [L]
```

What I am getting out of the rewrite rule is:

```
/modeles-voiture/Nissan/Qashqai 2
```

Note the missing + sign, which throws off my script at modeles.php

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450190/how-to-encode-the-plus-symbol-in-url

Comment: Start by figuring out where the + sign disappear. If you go to /modeles.php?brand=Nissan&model=Qashqai+2 will `$_GET['model']` contain the + character or not?

Comment: @turboHz, thanks for your reply. It could as well be related to that. I just tried to replace the + sign with %2b, making my URL /modeles-voiture/Nissan/Qashqai%2b2 but it gave me this:modeles-voiture/Nissan/Qashqai%2b2. So, the mechanics are not that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [B] flag.

Look at the answer to this question: [How to encode special characters using mod_rewrite & Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache)

> So then mod_rewrite changes your request '/tag/c++' to 'script.php?tag=c++'. But in a query string component in the application/x-www-form-encoded format, the escaping rules are very slightly different to those that apply in path parts. In particular, '+' is a shorthand for space (which could just as well be encoded as '%20', but this is an old behaviour we'll never be able to change now).
>
> So PHP's form-reading code receives the 'c++' and dumps it in your _GET as C-space-space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Replacing the + sign with #2O gives me the same results as replacing it with %2B, ie, returns me a URL like this modeles-voiture/Nissan/Qashqai%202, which can work fine if I just give a str_replace to get the + sign back. But that is valid for any special character I put in there. If I just replace the + sign in the original URL to say, '.', I can have it pass through the RewriteRule and then reconvert back at the destination php script. So, that's not really a solution, but a workaround.

Comment: Did you try using the [B] flag?

Comment: Not at first, but then I realized it and put it in. Did not work, though.  In any case, I made it work with the workaround mentioned in my previous comment, ie, just replacing + with something else that Apache does not have an issue with ('.' in the case).