# How to redirect ip to domain name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ip

I use Apache web-server and I want to redirect all urls from ip to domain. Here is the content of my website `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

According to some research, I guess I need something like this: (not sure)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^95\.216\.161\.63$
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ https://lamtakam.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I don't know how (in which part) should I add those threelines to the `.htaccess` file. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert IP redirect rule before or after `https/www` redirect rule:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^95\.216\.161\.63$
RewriteRule ^ https://lamtakam.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

If you want to make your IP matching condition more generic then use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\d+\.\d+\.
```

to be able to match any IP address.

Comment: I see, very good. Just a short question, why did you replaced `^([\s\S]*)$` with `.*`? .. You know, my website is in Persian, some URLs will be broken with `.*`, but `[\s\S]` matches everything, that's why I used it

Comment: Are you sure it gets broken by `.*`? I have tested non-English URLs in the past and everything was matched with `.*` because Apache encodes all UTF characters before we process them in `mod_rewrite` so all the whitespaces come as encoded. May be `B` can also be removed to make `.*` work. Please provide me an example URL that is broken with `.*` and I will surely learn something new.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564364/how-to-pass-a-persian-string-as-a-argument-in-the-url) is the problem we were involved with for about 1 week.

Comment: ok thanks, I will test it today itself. Meanwhile please keep using  `[\s\S]*`

Comment: Thanks. Also as my last question, do you think can I replace `.+` with `\s\S+` in `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]` too?

Comment: No that is not needed AFAIK because domain name can't allow all the characters that are allowed in REQUEST_URI

Comment: I've tried it and worked well, thx again. Just out of curiosity, no need to use `RewriteBase /` ?

Comment: Yes `RewriteBase /` is just a syntactic sugar here. It is used to prefix any relative targets and for non redirect rules (like last one) by default current path is already prefixed by `mod_rewrite` engine.