# Htaccess: inconsistent with GET request

Tags: php, .htaccess

These are two different requests. the articles are both `urlencoded()` in PHP. The first request will match but the second wouldn't probably because of the question mark (`?` or `%3F`); they both have the plus sign (`+` or `%2B`)

Here is my .htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^article~([^.]+)$ web/news/article.php?article=$1
```

My requests:

1

```
article~The-best-Android-Wear-smartwatch%2B12
```

2

```
article~Google-Play-Store-not-working%3F-Here-are-some-possible-fixes%2B10
```

I suspected that the presence of a question mark (`?` or `%3F`) in the second request could prevent it from working as it generate **error code 403 (Access forbidden!)**.

Comment: Why do you have `article~` and not `article=` in your expression?

Comment: @hd I intended to forward all `article~` to `article=` i.e if you visit `article~blah-blah` on your browser, PHP should see it as `aticle=blah-blah` that's the point.

Comment: Ah I got confused because your expression has `~` but your examples had `=`

Comment: if you're using PHP to formulate the URL it's much easier just to strip out non alphanumeric/dash characters from the URL line, it sure beats messing around with `htaccess` edgecases, because SEO doesn't care about `?` and nor do your site visitors

Comment: Also please check [This StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache). (both top two answers may be of interest to you)

Comment: @Martin That's could be a very nice idea, though I might be in trouble of stripping all non alphanumeric from my published posts URL (let me take that as **plan B** perhaps there would be a better solution). Thanks

Comment: How does your destination page load the data, does it search for the GET parameter in the Database? (I mean, does it matter what the title actually is?)