# mod_rewrite: target URL that contains an ampersand

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the following RewriteRule to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/coins-and-currency-counters.html$ /storefrontCommerce/categorybrowse.do?category-name=CHANGERS+%26+CURRENCY+COUNTER&path=&currentPage=1&numResults=10&expanded=false [R=301,B]
```

However, the rule doesn't handle the "%26" (or ampersand) correctly, and instead returns the following URL:

> /storefrontCommerce/categorybrowse.do?category-name=CHANGERS+6+CURRENCY+COUNTER&path=&currentPage=1&numResults=10&expanded=false

The following question seems closely related to my problem, but I don't understand the solutions offered:

[How to encode special characters using mod_rewrite & Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache)

How do I tell mod_rewrite to not convert the "%26" to "6"?

Comment: According to one of those answers, it should succeed if you add the NE flag `[R=301,B,NE]` and backslash-escape the encoded character `name=CHANGERS+\%26+CURRENCY+COUNTER`

Comment: And `[B]` shouldn't be necessary because you do not have any back references to escape.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  Do you want to post an answer to this question?

Comment: The other one already has solid answers. I'll link this to it instead of answering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode special characters using mod\_rewrite & Apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459667/how-to-encode-special-characters-using-mod-rewrite-apache)